# MySQL with C# bulk data import cursor with stored procedure throwing error Timeout expired.

Tags: c#, mysql, cursor, bulkinsert, timeoutexception

We have to import the data from excel/csv to the MySQL database tables.

We have implemented cursor in a stored procedure to import users and its details from the temporary table to the actual tables. All the validations and checks are applied in the cursor itself which takes a while to import a single record out of multiple records.

After importing the data(1000+ records) to the temporary table, the stored procedure with the cursor gets executed which throws below error:

Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Even after the application is stopped, the stored procedure keeps executing in the background and all the records are imported.

Can anyone please help with the solution to the timeout exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try after increasing the Command Timeout ?

Comment: Yes I tried, but its still giving the same error.